# SceneKit flattenCode function

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a node to which I add all of the objects I want to show on screen. These objects are taken from .dae files. All of the objects are added to a SCNNode called levelNode, then I add it to the parent:

```
parentNode.addChildNode(levelNode)
```

The problem occurs when I try to flatten the levelNode for optimisation (I kind of understood that by flattening the nodes I combine the textures and this should keep the frame rate at it's maximum) purposes and then add it to the parent node:

```
let flatLevelNode = levelNode.flattenedClone()
parentNode.addChildNode(flatLevelNode)
```

In the latter case nothing appears on screen.